# how do I hide scrollbars in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I have the following css

```
overflow: scroll;
```

How do I hide scrollbars in firefox and internet explorer?

I'm already using `overflow: hidden` on the parent element.

I have the following html

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="inner">
</div>
</div>
```

I have `overflow: scroll` on the inner element and `overflow: hidden` on the parent element.

I also have

```
.glb-nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

which hides scrollbars in firefox and safari.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to hire scroll bars, they work for free for everyone :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)